# Node.JS body parser issue

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, console

I'm attempting to send data from one machine to another in node.js.

I seem to be having some difficulty getting the parser to function correctly.
Here is my client and server code

**Client.JS**

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://192.168.1.225:3002',
    { form: { key: 'notyourmother' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

**Server.JS**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage');
console.log(req.body);
});

var server = app.listen(3002, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

When I run both snippets, the console outputs "{}".

What may I be doing incorrect?
Thank you!

Comment: Is it `console.log(body)` or `console.log(req.body);` which outputs {} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong body parser on the server side. `request` is sending a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request payload with your current client code. So simply swap out `bodyParser.json()` with something like `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })`.